# Train function metric option

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, caret

I have a question based on the train function from the caret package. I am relatively new to ML and am a little confused. I am using the random forest algorithm attempting to predict a continuous output variable with categorical and continuous input variables. I have used the previous line of code on a similar problem with a categorical output. However, I am confused on the default metric option.

```
rf_train <- train(Output~., data=training, method = "rf", importance=TRUE,do.trace=TRUE,
                  trControl = trainControl(method="cv",number=4),metric="RMSE")
```

R documentation defines it as...
A string that specifies what summary metric will be used to select the optimal model. By default, possible values are "RMSE" and "Rsquared" for regression and "Accuracy" and "Kappa" for classification. If custom performance metrics are used (via the summaryFunction argument in trainControl, the value of metric should match one of the arguments. If it does not, a warning is issued and the first metric given by the summaryFunction is used. (NOTE: If given, this argument must be named.)

From what I understand RMSE and Rsquared should be used if the output is continuous, and ROC is common for categorical variables. Is this correct in practice?

Comment: Yes, ROC is often recommended for classification. Caret has a `twoClassSummary` function that provides the ROC, so you can use it instead of accuracy. Do you have a coding question beyond that?

Comment: I guess what I am asking. Is RMSE a proper metric to evaluate the model using a continuous output?

Comment: Yes it is very standard to use the RMSE to quantify the performance of a regression model. Whether there is a better metric is heavily dependent on the particular use case. Voting to close as too broad :)